# Populate select with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two little issues when I populate my select with angularjs.

I wnat populate my select with results from an api rest (I used mocky)

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>My first app</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My first app</h1> 
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedTestAccount" 
    ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in testAccounts">
<option value="">Select Account</option>
</select>
{{error}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('test', []).controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.selectedTestAccount = null;
$scope.testAccounts = [];

$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a2112be2d0000040ee000aa'      
    }).then(function (result) {
    $scope.testAccounts = result;
}).catch(function (err) { $scope.error = err});;
});

})()
```

API: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a2112be2d0000040ee000aa

which returns:

```
{"id" : 1, "name" : "France - Mainland", "desc": "some description"}
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. doing like the above example, the select is rendered partially fine. If I open the select I can see:

[image]

as you can see I have the first field correct, but in the other undefined and I don't know why

2. The second problem is if I have a list of object from API, for example changing url of the call with http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a2132f32d00006116e00178, which returns:

   [{"id" : 1, "name" : "France - Mainland", "desc": "some description"},
   {"id" : 2, "name" : "Italy", "desc": "some description"}]

I have all option field like undefined (see picture below)

[image]

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your api returns only one data, which is an object. you need to push the response to your testAccounts array as follows,

```
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5a2112be2d0000040ee000aa'
  }).then(function(result) {
    $scope.testAccounts.push(result.data);
    console.log($scope.testAccounts);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    $scope.error = err
  });
```

[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/nk6zktU43YeSiZEVaSS8?p=preview)

Comment: This works only with url: https://www.mocky.io/v2/5a2112be2d0000040ee000aa
If you try with this http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a2132f32d00006116e00178 it doesn't work (the second api returns a list)

Comment: @Gjord83 as i explained above 2nd link returns array, so you need to assign directly. check here https://plnkr.co/edit/fFRtdE2oE3OWcow1tksM?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="selectedTestAccount" ng-if="item.name"
    ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in testAccounts">
<option value="">Select Account</option>
</select>
```

**ng-if will allow when only the value is defined**

Comment: thanks, but I would know why, there are some undefined fields, whether the api returns one object and no one undefined